# How to load external resources in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

In Angular 6, I was able to use external resources by adding below in `angular.json`

```
"assets": [
{"glob":"**/*", "input":"node_modules/xx", "output": "./yy"},
{"glob":"**/*", "input":"node_modules/mxgraph/javascript/src", "output": "./mxgraph"}
]
```

In Angular 7 it does not work anymore. How do I achieve it in Angular 7?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the period in the output path, and use a period for the input path. The output path is relative to the `dist` folder, and the input path is relative to the to where you run `ng build`.

```
"assets": [
   {"glob":"**/*", "input":"./node_modules/xx", "output": "/yy"},
   {"glob":"**/*", "input":"./node_modules/mxgraph/javascript/src", "output": "/mxgraph"}
]
```

> In Angular 7 it does not work anymore. How do I achieve it in Angular 7?

I don't think anything has changed between Angular 6 and 7 in regards to assert globs.

Please see the documentation:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-asset-configuration